# JavaScript and CSS text fade and SEO

Tags: javascript, seo, fading

I'm currently designing my first website and I want to use a carousel style fading image sequence. I also want to include text over this that fades in and out such as this:

http://jsfiddle.net/azzWZ/

My question is, would the fact that this is all fading in and out affect the google crawl of my page? I know that SEO is not a science (at least not outside Google HQ) so does anyone have any experience of this affecting their search ranking?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google grabs the page HTML - it doesn't "sit there and watch" your animation. In general, don't put SEO sensitive content in your slideshow. Make it plainly visible in your page.

Answer (score 0):

If search engines can see the text without JavaScript being enabled then it will afect your rankings.

Answer (score 0):

It will be seen by the crawler, but if the initial display via CSS is none, visibility hidden, or the foreground color matches the stated background too closely, the value is lower.

Specify a background color if the text is white... and hide it via script, not css at the start.  You should be okay.

Comment: In the example I linked they use display:none so are you saying that would be the 'wrong' way to go about doing it? I have no js knowledge so getting it hidden using script would mean a lot of searching - do you know of any decent scripts for doing this kind of thing?